# MYSQL + ERROR 771006 (HY000): Can't create database 'Test' (errno: 2)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am installing mysql on server and it i succesfuly done.

Now when I login as a root and try to create a database I get the following error.

```
**ERROR 771006 (HY000): Can't create database 'Test' (errno: 2)**
```

I have given permission to cd /var/lib/mysql

```
chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql
```

And also did the following steps:

```
shell> cd /var/lib
shell> chown -R mysql:mysql mysql
```

But still when I create the database I get the samee error.

Comment: This certainly wasn't a mysql-error-1064 type question.

Comment: Similar issue has been discussed on this mailing list thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sequel-pro/TBF1rAVwbRE. May be it is helpful to you.

Comment: Restarting the system seems to have fixed it for nearly all users.